# Данные с формы не проходят валидацию

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Имеется форма

```
<?=$form->field($model, '_author')->label('Имя')?>
<?=$form->field($model, '_email')->label('Email')?>
<?=$form->field($model, '_comment')->label('Комментарий')->textArea(['rows' => 3])?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-1">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

И обработчик

```
public function editComment($id)
{
    $comment = Comments::findOne($id);
    $comment->author = $this->_author;
    $comment->comment = $this->_comment;
    $comment->email = $this->_email;
    return $comment->save();
}
```

Правила валидации

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['_author', '_comment', '_email'], 'required'],
        [['_author', '_comment'], 'string'],
        ['_email', 'email']
    ];
}
```

При обновлении данных с валидированием обновление не происходит. Метод `$model->validate()` возвращает `false` хотя данные валидны. Приходиться использовать `$comment->save(false)`. Никак не могу понять, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в обработчике сделать так:

```
public function editComment($id)
{
    $comment = Comments::findOne($id);
    if ($comment->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect([куда-нибудь]);
    }
}
```

или сгенерируйте это все в gii, создайте там модель и CRUD. Это заметно упростит все.